# Keeping variable value in different activities Android Studio

Tags: android, variables

I have tabbed activities in my app. In each tab I have a (switch) button which toggles to on and off by clicking. As I move to another tab and come back to the same, it gets off. I want to keep its value so that it doesn't change when switching to other activities.

Layout(XML) code of the button:

```
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/b_btnlight"
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="ON"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="500dp"/>
```

The related tab activity:

```
bbtnlight = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_btnlight);

bbtnlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(bbtnlight.getText()=="ON")
                {bbtnlight.setText("OFF");
                    bbtnlight.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));}
                else
                {bbtnlight.setText("ON");
                    bbtnlight.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));}
            }
        });
```

When the button is OFF, its color is red and the text equals ON and vice versa. For the other tab activities, I have the same thing. I appreciate if you could help me in this case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to make a class with static variables to hold the value during the applications lifetime

```
public class GlobalVars {
    public static boolean isLightOn;
}
```

This way you can get and set GlobalVars.isLightOn from anywhere in your application. Set it to true when you use the switch and when you return back you check this variable if it's true or false. **When you close your application the variable will be reset to false**

Another option is to use `SharedPreferences` to store your data, this way when you close your app, the data will be there if you open it again

Comment: Thanks, I needed this GlobalVars actually. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In Android, you can never be sure when your Activities will fall out of memory if they're not onscreen.  If you want your app to remember values, you have to find a place to permanently or semi-permanently store them, even if the user switches to another activity, another app, shuts off the screen, or even turns off the device.  You can't assume that just because the activity is no longer on screen that the user is done with it.  For example, if the user gets a phone call while using your app, they'd probably like to return where they left off.

There are a few places where you can store persistent data in Android.  Here are the top 2:

1. Shared Preferences - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html
2. SqlLite - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Answer (score 1):

use [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

Storing Data

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Retrieving Data

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

You just set it in **SharedPreferences**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit();

onCreate(){
     checkButton();
     bbtnlight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkButton();
            }
        });   
}

private void checkButton() {
    if (pref.getBoolean("is_button_checked", false)) {
        bbtnlight.setText("ON");
        bbtnlight.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
        editor.putBoolean("is_button_checked", true);
    } else {
        bbtnlight.setText("OFF");
        bbtnlight.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
        editor.putBoolean("is_button_checked", false);
    }
}
```